Подставить значение из определенной ячейки
Скрипт ищет все значения "test 3" и выделяет их курсивом. Как сделать так чтобы вместо фиксированого значения "test 3' подставлялось значение из  определенной ячейки?
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set sheet name.
  const searchTexts = ['text 3'];
  const textStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setBold(true)
    .setForegroundColor("black")
    .build();

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const srcRange = sheet.getRange("A1:C100");
  const richTextValues = srcRange.getRichTextValues();
  const updatedRichTextValues = richTextValues.map((r) =>
    r.map((richTextValue) => {
      const object = {
        richText: richTextValue,
        texts: searchTexts,
        textStyle: textStyle,
      };
      return RichTextAssistant.setTextStyleInCellText(object);
    })
  );
  srcRange.setRichTextValues(updatedRichTextValues);
}


Строку в коде перепишите

какую именно???

Илья, предоставьте ссылку на таблицу, где указан полный код. Я так понимаю этот код или вам писали, или вы его где-то нашли. Он как минимум неполный. Ссылку не обязательно предоставлять на рабочую таблицу, можно сделать копию
